# how do you take input from keyboard in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to take the choices based on the menu from shell script in Gitlab. Is this feasible or not from Gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: what choices you wanna go with ??

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: show_menus() {
        echo " M A I N - M E N U"
        echo "1. MY_prod component status"
        echo "2. MY_prod Hardware Check"
        echo "3. MY_prod FS Check"
        echo "4. MY_prod System Service"
        echo "5. MY_prod VCS Health Check"
        echo "14. Check Filesystem "
        echo "15. Check MY_prod  Audit Status"
        echo "16. Check Parallel synchs"
        echo "0. Exit"

Comment: So that based on menu I can select the options and run the needful function..